# Tool Suite for a basic Web App

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking for suggestions on an Eclipse based suite to display a summary list of rows in a database and then select an item for detailed display.

It needs to: Have a visual designer, drag and drop. Java as a fairly strong preference. Reasonably quick to pick up and learn.

Comment: Which operating system?  Free or paid?  Help us help you!  :-)

Comment: Cross platform hence the "Java ...". Deployed to Tomcat or Glassfish.